# private final Card[]cards, how do I use this in another class

Tags: java, arrays, implementation, reusability

```java
Private final Card[] cards;
Public Deck() {
    this.cards = new Card[52];
    int i = 0;
    for (Suit suit : Suit.values()) {
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values()) {
            cards[i++] = new Card(rank, suit);
        }
    }
}
```

This is an array of cards it works in the class it is made called Deck. I am trying to make a card game that implements this along with other classes. I want the Deck class to be reusable so it works in any card game. I want a Deck of cards essentially. Now I know it works because I can use the `printDeck()` method I have in the same class to print off a deck of cards but don't know how or even if I can call it in a card game.
Why would I need a getter when the new operator creates an instance of Deck which is essentially an array of Card [52] cards? I want this Deck to be reusable so I don't have to rewrite it for every different type of card game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define a getter method in your `Deck` class as below :

```
public Card[] getCards() {
   return cards;
}
```

Them from another class you can use this getter method once you have a `Deck` object :

```
Card[] cards = yourDeckObject.getCards();
```